# Where can I find mysql-devel?

Tags: raspbian, mysql

I installed mysql / apache and php. It is all working fine but now I want to use mysql calls in C programs. Therefore I need mysql-devel. Can't find it.

Comment: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/mysql/setup-mysql-c-access

Comment: The easiest way to find stuff like this is `apt-cache search mysql | grep "-dev"`.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache search mysql | grep "-dev"
grep: invalid argument 'ev' for '--directories'   This is the result after a test with copy / past.  Looks as if the -d is interpreted as directory.

Comment: Oh yeah -- sorry.   Doesn't work with single quotes either, which makes sense since either way it is just a string passed through.  Anyway, you can escape it with a slash: `grep "\-dev"` (tested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql libs are split into client and server in apt...

Try:
`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqld-dev`

Comment: I installed both libs.  When I compile my program, mysql.h is still missing. Where should header files be (which directory)? Where are are for instance the standard C header files? I have them since compilation of a simple program using stdio.h compiles fine.  As you can see .. newbe ... grrrrr

Comment: Try `apt-file search mysql.h` (you may have to install `apt-file` first).  In this case I think [what you are looking for](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=jessie&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=mysql.h) is `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: All, did install the libraries but no change. Search for mysql-h was empty (did an update) .  I'm afread I have to compile and install the mysql connector/C directly from the MYSQL website.

Comment: It's part of libmysqlclient.dev. (it's just not included in the standard search path...) See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604228/mysql-h-file-cant-be-found

Comment: All,  after the installation of the two libraries : libmysqlclient-dev libmysqld-dev   I used the instruction as explaned .. see link   http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html and whaaaw .. the C program with SQL "calls" compiles nicely.   Thank you all for your input and help.

Comment: The topic can be closed as SOLVED .. can somebody do that. Thank you.